# Children of an array element

Tags: jquery

I'm a beginner in jQuery and here's what I'm trying to do:

- Find all elements (let's call them boxes to avoid confusion later) with class "chosen" and assign a number to each.
- In each of those boxes, find all input elements in them.
- To each input element's name add it's box number. For instance, if in 3rd box there was a text input element called "login", it should be renamed to "login3".

Here's the code I made so far:

```
boxes = $('.chosen');
for(a = 0; a < boxes.length; a++) {
    inputsinboxes = boxes[a].children('input');
    for(b = 0; b < inputsinboxes.length; b++) {         
        inputsinboxes[b].name = inputsinboxes[b].name + (a+1);
    }
}
```

I'm stuck though since it keeps telling me `boxes[a].children` is not a function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use array index notation (brackets) to access an element from a jQuery object, you don't get a jQuery object back. You get the underlying DOM node. http://api.jquery.com/get/

Start by using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to make this more idiomatic jQuery:

```
$('.chosen').each(function (i) {
    $(this).children('input').prop('name', function () {
        return this.name + (i+1);
    });
});
```

Comment: @Lix it's well-documented, and has nothing specifically to do with _anonymous_ functions. A named one would work just as well. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing raw javascript intuitions with how jquery operates. Try this on for size

```
$('.chosen').each(function(index) {
    $('input', this).each(function() {
        $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + (index + 1));
    });
});
```

Comment: Why keep your own `a` index when you get one for free when using `.each()`?

Comment: @MattBall Thank you! I never looked into each deep enough to care about it's parameters, you've just made my future "each" endeavors that much sweeter :)

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. Just a small correction, a should be incremented after whole box is finished, so:

`var a = 1;$('.chosen').each(function() {
 $('input', this).each(function() {
  $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + (a));
 });
 a++;
});`

Comment: Ah, my apologies, using the index counter on the .each loop as @MattBall suggested fixes this issue as well, by using the outside counter :) Glad to see you got it working even with my initial bug :)

Comment: Another way to fix that would have been to start with `a = 0`, or use `++a` instead of `a++`.

Answer (score 1):

`boxes[a]` is a `DOMElement`, not a jQuery object; so you can't use the jQuery `children()` method on it.

Instead you have to wrap it in a jQuery object first:

```
boxes = $('.chosen');
for(a = 0; a < boxes.length; a++) {
    inputsinboxes = $(boxes[a]).children('input');
    for(b = 0; b < inputsinboxes.length; b++) {         
        inputsinboxes[b].name = inputsinboxes[b].name + (a+1);
    }
}
```

---

1. Also note that you should declare your variables with a `var` to stop them being made implicit globals;

   ```
   var boxes = $('.chosen');
   ```
2. Consider using the more common [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) function in jQuery rather than a `for` loop. Coupled with the using [`prop()` as a setter](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) and providing a function, you can shorten your code to just:

   ```
   $('.chosen').each(function (i) {
       $(this).children('input').prop('name', function (j, curr) {
           return curr + (i+1);
       });
   });
   ```